# Updating an attribute of an element isnt affecting the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have loaded a set of elements in from my backend using ajax and then displayed them on my website, this happens multiple times and this includes radio inputs which are grouped togther using the name attribute i am attempting to seperate these radios into there own groups on my page so that i could have multiple groups of radios that dont affect each other.

```
<div class="row w-50 RadioGroup">
    <div class="form-check w-50">
        <input class="form-check-input OneAnswer" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1"
            checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            User has to select one correct answer
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check w-50">
        <input class="form-check-input AllAnswers" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
            User has to select all correct answers
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code above shows the radio elements that are shown i have written some jquery to change the name and when i console.log the name it does in fact change but the chnages arent shown in the DOM and because of this the radios all still afect each other rather than just the radios with the same name.

The code to change the radio names is below

```
    $(Div).find(":radio").each(function (index, value) {
        $(value).get(0).setAttribute("name", $(value).get(0).getAttribute("name") + RadiosCount)
        console.log($(value).get(0).getAttribute("name"))
    })
    RadiosCount++;
}
```

Ive also tried changing the propertey as well the only way i can get the radios to behave properley is to change the radios name in the inspector.

So to summarise how do i change the name attribute of the elements so that the radios dont all affect each other? only the two that should affect each other in there own group.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over each group and use the index of that group to adjust name of the radios within each group instance.

The other issue is needing to modify duplicate IDs and `for` values since a clicking a label with a for needs a unique reference value

```js
$('.RadioGroup').each(function(groupIndex){
  $(this).find(':radio').each( function(i){
       this.id = [this.id ,groupIndex,i].join('-');
       this.name = this.name + groupIndex;       
       $(this).next('label').attr('for', this.id)
  });  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row w-50 RadioGroup">
    <div class="form-check w-50">
        <input class="form-check-input OneAnswer" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1"
            checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            User has to select one correct answer
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check w-50">
        <input class="form-check-input AllAnswers" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
            User has to select all correct answers
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="row w-50 RadioGroup">
    <div class="form-check w-50">
        <input class="form-check-input OneAnswer" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1"
            checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            Group 2 #1
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check w-50">
        <input class="form-check-input AllAnswers" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
           Group 2 #2
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have looped over the groups and i have tried changing the name using the attr command and this didnt work so i used the get command to try it in js instead neither of these methods worked because although the name changes the DOM isnt affected and therefore the radios are all still in one big group rather than many groups of 2

Comment: Ahh ... it's because of the `for` being the same. Give me a minute to fix

Comment: See update that also tweaks the id's and `for` values. How are these generated that they have duplicates to start with?

Comment: They are generated from a HTML file that is grabbed from the backend vai ajax this will still change the name in the same way i changed it that didnt work though and changing the id to match the for element is not required although i will add it in future but this dosent solve the problem of why the name attr changes when logged but that changed isnt reflected in the DOM

Comment: working fine in my answer now. I'm changing the property which won't affect the attribute in live html. Yes it matters regarding duplicate `for` on labels

Comment: the for links the label to the radio so if u click the label it will activate the radio i know this and planned to add it after but for now i need to work on changing the name since if i click on the radio they are all still in one group

Comment: Do you see that bug in my answer? It works fine for me. Are you sure you are doing this after the ajax has inserted them?

Comment: Thanks ive found the bug in my code Div was the html after it had been parsed but not the html that was inserted i had assumed this was the same thanks.